# Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" for just a specific package?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, sudo

I normally edit my `/etc/sudoers` file to include my username with some options.

When using `apt-get` to upgrade, I get the prompt to choose the newer version (dist-version) or my edited version, if the `sudoers` package has an upgrade.

How do I disable this prompt for *just* this package? In all other cases, yes I would like to be prompted, so I can see a diff. But in this case, I really don't want the prompt.

Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of editing `/etc/sudoers`, add a file to `/etc/sudoers.d`/ Check `/etc/sudoers.d/README`

Comment: Huh, that's convenient, never thought of that. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. By default, /etc/sudoers.d  is *not* searched.  I have to uncomment a line in /etc/sudoers, which kind of beats the purpose in the first place of not touching the default configuration file.

Comment: Since 12.04, `/etc/sudoers.d` *is* searched. If you read the README, like I asked you to, you'd see that it doesn't do so for older versions and systems upgraded from older versions.